# How to JOIN by date columns?

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables with the structure of

```
CREATE TABLE table1
(
Month date,
Value1 varchar(255),
PRIMARY KEY(Month)
) ENGINE=InnoDB

CREATE TABLE table2
(
Day date,
Value2 varchar(255),
PRIMARY KEY(Day)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

In table1, the date values are stored in the form of

```
2018-04-01
2018-03-01
2018-02-01
2018-01-01
```

and in table2

```
2018-04-01
2018-04-02
2018-04-03
2018-04-04
2018-04-05
```

How can I `JOIN` two tables to have the month value (Value1 from table1) for each row of table2?

The desirable result

```
Day           Month        Value1        Value2
2018-04-01    2018-04-01   
2018-04-02    2018-04-01
2018-04-03    2018-04-01
2018-04-04    2018-04-01
2018-04-05    2018-04-01
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use LEFT JOIN + DATE_FORMAT:

```
SELECT
  t2.Day,
  t1.Month,
  t1.Value1,
  t2.Value2
FROM Table2 t2 LEFT JOIN Table1 t1 ON DATE_FORMAT(t2.Day, '%Y-%m-01') = t1.Month
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/920c79/1

Answer (score 3):

If you aren't sure that all of your dates in the second table end are on the first day, you can be sure the comparison on year/month with `EXTRACT( YEAR_MONTH FROM datecol)` like this,

```
SELECT
  t2.Day,
  t1.Month,
  t1.Value1,
  t2.Value2
FROM Table2 t2
LEFT JOIN Table1 t1
  ON EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM t2.Day) = EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM t1.Month)
```

It is likely faster regardless, unless you have an index on `t1.month`

Answer (score 0):

You can treat the `DATEs` as strings:

```
WHERE LEFT(t1.Month, 7) = LEFT(t2.Day, 7)
```